# Grails 2.1.1 - table from child list not sorting in parent show view -arrghh

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have 2 domains

```
Portfolio
  static hasMany [publications: Publication]
  String portfolioName

Publication
  static belongsTo = [portfolio: Portfolio]
   String publicationName
   String pubcontent
   String published
   String publisheddate
```

I am wanting to `g:render` or `tmpl` the Publication list view or a new partial view in the show view for the Portfolio domain. This all works fine and displays perfectly if I adjust the publication list view to pass the portfolio params in portfolioInstance?.publications.

**Problem:**
When I want to sort on the table headings from the publications list view, the sort moves the data around but does not follow any sort order. I have tried all domain tricks, such as List publications, comparators, etc., I have messed around with modifying the view using `.sort{a,b-> a.id.compareTo(b.id)}` but am still not getting them sorted correctly.

How do I get these columns to sort correctly? To reiterate, I need or want all columns in the table to be sortable.

What I have done so far and not worked:

- `<g:sortableColumn` is in the view
- domain class Portfolio used List publications
- comparators inline in the view
- many other things.

Where am I going wrong? Do I need to write a new method under the portfolio controller to handle a list action and params sort or can I do something in the views to fix this.

**example** list view - cut down for brevity

```
<g:each in="${portfolioInstance?.publications }" status="i" var="pubs">
<g:link controller="publication" action="show" id="${publicationInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: publicationInstance, field: "publicationName")}</g:link>

<td><g:formatDate date="${pubs.publisheddate}" /></td>

<td>${fieldValue(bean: publicationInstance, field: "published")}</td>
```

**Controllers**

Standard grails generated controller

```
def show(Long id) {
    def portfolioInstance = Portfolio.get(id)
    portfolioInstance.properties=params

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 52)
    if (params.sort==null){
        params.sort = "published"

    }
    [publicationInstanceList: Publication.list(params), publicationInstanceTotal: Publication.count()]
```

Comment: Are you using scaffolding? I didn't see a published field in your domain class...

Comment: argh yes sorry I cut down the class fields to keep content small. will add the correct fields into domain

Comment: argh yes sorry I cut down the class fields to keep content small. will add the correct fields into domain. Yes predominantly these have been scaffold generated views. I included the g:each in=portfolioInstance so that on the publications associated with the portfolio would display in the table

Comment: Can you post your controller too?

Comment: Controllers are grails generated controllers showing full crud operations. no static scaffold = in controllers.

Comment: Suggestion: add logSql = true in the datasource to see the query that Grails generates.

Answer (score 0):

See section 6.5.2 ("Default Sort Order") of the [GORM Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html).  You just need to add

```
static mapping = {
    sort "publicationName"
}
```

in your Publication class if you want that to be the field that Publications are sorted by.

Comment: I want all table columns in the table to be sortable when user clicks the table headings. therefore I need all class fields to be sortable not just one. Thanks anyway have tried this